# CSS: How does youtube change its appearance based on screen size?

Tags: html, css

I'm interested in how youtube changes it's appearance based on the screen size without using javascript.

Try it yourself: 
go to youtube and take a look at the navbar if the window size is smaller than 700px the logo changes.

This works even with javascript disabled.

I inspected the resources of the html css files of the page but couldn't find out how youtube does it.

If anyone knows the trick or has a guess - please answer.

Comment: lookup css media queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use mediaqueries a CSS3 function that is related to Responsive Design, this allow you to define in which size (known as breakpoints) the browser should render the website with a different set of CSS properties.

If you have a website with the following css stylesheet

```
body {
  background: black;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background: gold;
  }
}
```

Explanation: when the browser or screen width is over 600px, the body background should be black. In case the browser or screen is under 600px width, the body background should be gold.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background: gold;
  }
  h1 {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Demonstration</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

:) Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

they use the `Responsive Web Design (Media Queries)` :

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp